# Theoretical Math Sequence Proof

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

Suppose that {xn} is a sequences such that every subsequence {xni} has a subsequence {xnmi} that converges to x. Show that {xn} is bounded.

I tried to do a proof by contradiction but am not sure if the proof is sufficient.

I said: Suppose {Xn} is unbounded.

Then, ∀ M∈R s.t. ∀ n∈N ∃ |Xn| > M.

Thus, ∀ subsequences that contain the set of n's we have that ∀ M∈R s.t. ∀ i∈N ∃ |Xni| > M.

Therefore, ∀ subsequences that contain the set of i's we have that ∀ M∈R s.t. ∀ m∈N ∃ |Xnmi| > M.

But, since we know {Xnmi} converges to x the subsequence cannot be unbounded.

Therefore, {Xn} must be bounded.

Is this proof sufficient. Any corrections or suggestions you have is appreciated.

Comment: [MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: What needs to be formatted? It looks fine to me. Sorry I am new here.